# IOS-Swift: How to convert the filesystem URL of the video (in gallary) to NSData?

Tags: swift

I got the filesystem URL by using image picker in Swift. I tried many ways to convert this URL to NSData of the content of that video but all failed. Here are my attempts:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        var videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
        var videoFileURL = videoDataURL.filePathURL
        println("ifURL1: \(videoFileURL!.isFileReferenceURL())") // false
        //var videoPath = videoDataURL 
        var error: NSError?

        var videoPath:String = "\(videoDataURL)"         
        println("ifURL2: \(videoDataURL.isFileReferenceURL())") // false

        var videoData = fileURL
        var videoData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(videoPath)
        var video = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile("\(videoDataURL)")
        var videoData = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: videoPath)!
```

Anyway I want to get the fileReferenceURL to the video I picked. So How to convert filesystem URL to fileReferenceURL? Thanks a lot if anyone could help me out!

Comment: NVM I got it months ago but I forgot to update. There is a function in swift that could get it.